# Dealing with a list of tuples - SQLite3 & Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I am using a database to return a couple of values I place there. Let's just say the data is `google, yahoo, bing`.

**The Code**

```
dbCursor.execute('''SELECT ticker FROM SearchEngines''')
allEngines = dbCursor.fetchall()
for engine in engines:
        print engine
```

Yields the following result:

```
(u'google')
(u'yahoo')
(u'bing)
```

This is troublesome because I require the result to be appended to a url in a string format. Does anybody know a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: Just use `print engine[0]` or `for (engine,) in engines:`.

Comment: @cdonts this worked perfectly. Thank you. Can you please submit your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchall()` always returns a tuple, even if you're just selecting one field. So...

```
for engine in engines:
    print engine[0]
```

Or:

```
for (engine,) in engines:
    print engine
```

Hope this helps.